# Using fusion tables with app inventor as a database

Tags: google-fusion-tables, app-inventor

Easy to answer question ( I hope)

Need to use fusion tables with app inventor as a database but need to have every app access it without having to log in with user id.

Does app inventor have that functionality? Believe I need to set up API for 'installed applications' but do not know where in app inventor I need to enter the SHA1 code.

App is to 'anonymously' update database without needing to log in.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible with the built-in [Fusiontables Controls](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/not-ready-prime-time.html#FusiontablesControl), see also the notes in the [Pizza Party tutorial](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/pizzaparty.html):

> NOTE about Sharing Fusion Tables: To share a FusionTable with others,
>   you have to invite each person individually, the same way you would
>   share a private google doc. There is no way to share write privileges
>   to a FusionTable with the public. Public access is restricted to
>   read-only.

However this is possible with the [App Inventor - Fusiontable interface](http://puravidaapps.com/taifunFT2.php) using the web component. To prepare the login free access, do a run with the interface with your login and store the received refresh token as variable in your app. Then you can build your app, publish it and run the interface with the stored authorization without need to login anymore. The user will then access your fusion table with owner permissions.

See also [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949701/use-fusion-table-like-a-database-with-php-and-how-to-dismiss-the-prompt-page-whe) and [here](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/articles/oauthfusiontables)

> **Application 1 - Using Fusion Tables like a Database***
>
> ...
>
> In other words, if you own a Fusion Table in your own account that you
>   want to serve as a database in your application, you simply need to
>   get the access and refresh tokens for that account, and use the access
>   token for all requests to Fusion Tables. When the access token
>   expires, a 401: Unauthorized message is returned, and the refresh
>   token can be used to request a new access token.
>
> ...
>
> You can then securely save the access and refresh tokens somewhere
>   accessible by your application, and use them in your code to make the
>   requests to Fusion Tables.

**EDIT**: You now can find a [running example here](http://puravidaapps.com/fusionDB.php).

Comment: Thanks Taifun. I was beginning to think that. Will give it a go and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a database for your app, also consider using Google Cloud SQL which offers familiar MySQL functionality on the cloud.  https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/